# Going to a wedding of a gentile

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, gentiles, wedding, meal-seudah

It says in SA YD Siman 152 Sif 1 that it's ossur to go to a wedding (seudah) that a gentile is making for his son. The Shach and Taz both discuss over there if for reasons of "aiveh" if one is allowed to go (meaning that the gentile would get upset with you if you didn't come.) The Shach has a tzrich iyun in this. The Taz however is seemingly more machmir.

While it seems from Shulchan Aruch that it would be a problem to go to the seudah (assuming as well it's in a hall and there is no other problem of entering a church, etc.) Are there any heterim for this? Are there poskim that rely on the Shach in this matter? Would it help if along with having their own food would sit at a separate table?

(The person making the wedding let's say is a business partner or neighbor that one is friendly with.)

While I realize in a practical situation one should ask their Rabbi what to do, I'm asking here for sources on the issue and if there are any makilim in the poskim.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen responsa on this subject in the eretz chemda responsa. You may look there. 
The responsa is called במראה הבזק. I think there is a more direct answer there but i found the following: (vol.6 q.61) one may take part in a simcha but may not eat. one may not attend any religious ceremony that involves elements of Avodah Zarah, calling jesus god would definitely fall under that category, and some would argue that even a reform ceremony would. for further reference i have quoted the whole answer ad there is a link here to the whole volume.
In place of Eivah, one is permitted to drink kosher drinks. Please note that kosher drinks do not include kosher wine seeing as wine opened by a goy is not kosher, and most poskim give that same judgment to wine served by a non religious person, therefor one must not drink wine served at weddings even in Israel, unless they have opened the bottle themselves and pored it as well.

[link to volume](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/Data/UploadedFiles/FtpUserFiles/Books/shotBemarehH/6.pdf)

### סא. השתתפות בטקסי שאלה: בני דתות  ע  ג  תרבותיי  טבעי קשרי תרבותית באופייה, ולבני הקהילה היהודית באופ  החברה באוסטרליה היא רב ?  והינדוניסטיי  בודהיסטיי  ומקדשי  : כנסיות, מסגדי  מותר להיכנס לבתי תפילה שלה  ובאיזה תנאי  אחרות. הא אוכל כשר?  שלה  מותר לאכול באירועי  , והא  פסיבית בטקסיה  מותר להשתת  הא תשובה:  : שאלת הכניסה לבתי תפילה של דתות אחרות, ושאלת הנוכחות וההשתתפות בטקסי  נחלקת לב' חלקי  התשובה לשאלת .  שלה . של פיקוח נפש 3  איבה 2, למעט במקרי  לא משו  מטרה 1, וא  להיכנס לבית עבודה זרה לשו א. 1. אי .6 5 והינדוניסטיי  בודהיסטיי  מקדשי כנסיות נוצריות 4, וכ  2. בגדר בית עבודה זרה נכללי בזה בעיה של דרכי , כשאי  מכ  שראוי להימנע ג  בית עבודה זרה 7, ויש אומרי  בו משו 3. מותר להיכנס למסגד, ואי .8 שלו  א  הטבלה לנצרות וכדו', א של עבודה זרה, כגו  אלמנטי  של דתות אחרות הכוללי  או לצפות בטקסי  להשתת ב. 1. אי . בפועל בטקס 9  משתתפי אי . של עבודה זרה 10  בו אלמנטי דת אחרת, כאשר אי מניעה להיות נוכח באירוע שמחה או אבל של ב 2. אי  במקו  אוכל כשר. וג  מביא את האוכל מהבית או שיש ש  א  לאכול בסעודת חתונה של גוי, וא 3. בכל מקרה, אי . איבה 12  חשש כשרות מותר במקו  בה שאי  לשתות משקי  איבה אסור הדבר 11 , א תקופת הגלות גזרו גזרות  תקופת הכנסת הגדולה ולאור  בשולי התשובה כי גדולי ישראל, החל מאבות האומה דר  נוסי , כתריס כנגד ההתבוללות. מנהיגי הקהילות בימינו  ישראל לאומות העול להבדיל חברתית בי ותיקנו תקנות שמטרת . שיקול חשוב זה בכל החלטה שכזו 13  ג לקחת בחשבו  צריכי מבאר בפירוש  נפסק להלכה בשו"ע (יו"ד סי' קמט סע' א). המשנה עוסקת בעיר שיש בה עבודה זרה, והרמב"  1 משנה (עבודה זרה יא ע"ב), וכ  סי' קנ סע' א) שמצווה להתרחק מדר  נפסק בשו"ע (ש  להיכנס לבית עבודה זרה ודאי שאסור, וכ  לגור בעיר כזאת, א  המשניות שאנו אנוסי בתשובה הבאה.  עיי  ס; ג תשובות קיב, קיד; ה תשובה עה). וכ  . וראה עוד בשו"ת "במראה הבזק" (א תשובות נט  אלילי עוד בשו"ת "במראה הבזק" (ג תשובה קיד).  2 שו"ת "יביע אומר" (ב יו"ד סי' יא) ושו"ת "יחוה דעת" (ד סי' מה). ועיי 3 סי' קנ סע' ג).  הרמ"א (שו"ע ש 4 בשו"ת  ); ועיי  ז יו"ד סי' יב) וה"יחוה דעת" (ש  וכ  אליעזר" (יד סי' צא), ה"יביע אומר" (ש  ה"אגרות משה" (יו"ד ג סי' קכט סע' ו), ה"צי .  אסור להיכנס לבתי תפילת  , עדיי  עובדי עבודה זרה גמורי  די  לנוצרי  אי  א  "במראה הבזק" (א תשובה נט), שג – מפי  את פסל מייסד דת  עובדי  בלבד, בפועל ההמוני  עבודה זרה אלא אורח חיי  בה פולח  שאי  פי שיש ממאמיני דת זו הטועני  על  5 א כרב בהונג קונג ומשמש עכשיו ברבנות בניו יורק.  הרב יעקב קרמאייר, שכיה גמורה – מפי הרב קרמאייר הנ"ל.  6 דת זו הנה עבודת אלילי  (מאכלות אסורות פרק יא הל' ז) שהישמעאלי  בדברי הרמב"  יצחק" (או"ח סי' יא) ושו"ת "יביע אומר" (ז יו"ד סי' יב), ויסוד  7 שו"ת "עי אליעזר" (יד סי'  סע' ה). וה"צי  סי' קמו) והרמ"א (ש  " (ש  המחבר ב"בית יוס  פסקו הטור (יו"ד סי' קכד), מר  עובדי עבודה זרה; וכ  אינ כבר השיג עליו ב"יביע  עובדי עבודה זרה. א  יש די  למוסלמי  סא ע"ב) שג  (סנהדרי  להיכנס למסגד, ויסודו בדברי הר"  צא) פסק שאי  נכנסי  כ פי  על  מסגד, וא  מערת המכפלה הקימו הערבי  שהמציאות היא שבתו  , והוסי  ולא כר"  ), שנפסק להלכה כרמב"  אומר" (ש פסק להיתר הגרח"ד הלוי בשו"ת "עשה  זה עיקר ראייתו. וכ  אי  שיש לחלק, א  מראיה זו, שייתכ  עיו  להתפלל. וצרי  וצדיקי  גאוני  לש רב" (א סי' נט).  ל  שאינה עבודה זרה, כיוו  בית תפילה של דת הכופרת בתורה, א  להיכנס לשו  " עח, א, 11 ) שאי  ההר (מובאת בספר "צידה לדר  8 דעת הרב מ ראיה ממערת המכפלה,  לתת כבוד לדת הכופרת בתורה. ולפי דבריו אי  לה כבוד, ואי  שיסוד האיסור להיכנס לבית עבודה זרה הוא מצד שנות .  המקודש ליהודי  כבוד למסגד, אלא כניסה למקו  בכניסה מת  אי  שש 9 בשו"ת "במראה הבזק" (א תשובה ס).  ועיי  , וא  מתיה  לנח  ". והובא בשו"ע (יו"ד סי' קנא סע' יב) שמותר א  עניי ישראל מפני דרכי שלו  ע  עניי גויי  (סא ע"א): "קוברי  10 גיטי בשו"ת  , משמע שלהיות נוכח מותר. לגבי תפילה משותפת עיי  שאסרו רק לאכול בסעודת חתונת  עניי ישראל, ולגבי שמחה ראה לקמ  כשאי .  שונה מגויי  דינ  לפי דבריו ש  , א  (סי' נז) לגבי קראי  בשו"ת הרא"  "במראה הבזק" (ג תשובה קיב). ועיי )  (ש  ) והש"  שה"פרישה" (ש  איבה אסור, וא  ) שאפילו במקו  11 עבודה זרה (ח ע"א), ונפסק בשו"ע (יו"ד סי' קנב סע' א). ודעת הט"ז (ש שהתיר  איבה ה"אגרות משה" (יו"ד ב סי' קיז) – מכ  במקו  הכריעו לאסור א  לא הכריעו להיתר. וכ  ה  איבה, ג  במקו  נסתפקו מה הדי רק שתייה, שהיא עראי, וה"משנה הלכות" (ז סי' קיח). 12 איבה.  ), שהשתייה נחשבת לעראי ולא נאסרה במקו  ה"אגרות משה" (ש 13 חכמה" (ויקרא כו, מד).  במסתו החשובה של בעל ה"מש  עיי

Comment: Yaakov, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for providing this reference! If you can [edit] in more information about the work you're citing, more precise references, more information about the rulings and their reasoning, etc., that would make this answer even more valuable. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/ebooks.asp?lang=en&top=1&PageId=28) the responsa you're talking about?

Comment: @IsaacMoses In 6:61 they permit attending but forbid eating. However, in cases of 'eivah' they permit drinking plain drinks.

Comment: Yes that is it. I don't have access to my books till next week. That is amazing, I didn't know they had it online, thanks.

Comment: Most Christian weddings don't serve much food, at least not at the reception, which is usually much lighter than the most modest Jewish "shmorg."  Even non-Jews know to eat before they go (unless there is a specific dinner invitation).

Comment: @BruceJames, I've observed some variation there based on either or both of denomination and nationality, but I don't have enough data to know which case is my typical.

Comment: Also not [Rambam Hilchos Avodat Kochavim 9:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912368/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Nine.htm) *When an idolater makes a [wedding] party for his son or daughter, it is forbidden to benefit from the feast. It is even forbidden for a Jew to eat and drink his own food there, since it is being consumed at a celebration of idolaters.*